# Compile-time packet construction in Rust

Tags: rust, metaprogramming

I have a C++ program where I've used template metaprogramming to generate small binary-format packets to be sent "over the wire", which gives better safety and clarity than a more naive approach of allocating a fixed-size buffer and copying various data items into it using calculated-by-hand offsets.

```
int foo(int fd, long long data1, float f1)
{
    auto m = membuf()
             .append<char>(0xAA).append<char>(0xBB)  // header
             .append(data1)
             .append(f1)
             .append(555); // in the pipe (arbitary extra data)
    return write(fd, m.data(), m.size());
}
```

This would send a packet consisting of the two bytes `0xAA` and `0xBB`, (for example) 8 bytes from `data1`, 4 bytes from `f1`, and 4 bytes forming `555`. (Actual sizes of `int` and so on would depend on compiler/architecture details of course, but I could also use eg `uint64_t` type for precise control).

(Note: The full implementation of `membuf` isn't really relevant to the question, but you can see it here if interested: https://godbolt.org/z/sr0Cuu)

The important characteristics in this case are that:

- no heap allocation is involved, and
- the size of the data packet and the offsets of each of the values are calculated at compile time
- it's all standard C++, no extensions, no experimental features (in fact it's C++11)

As it happens, this is compiled into a very efficient sequence of instructions which simply allocates the buffer on the stack and writes each value to the correct place within it:

```
foo(int, long long, float):
        subq    $40, %rsp
        movl    $-17494, %eax
        movl    $18, %edx
        movq    %rsi, 2(%rsp)
        movq    %rsp, %rsi
        movw    %ax, (%rsp)
        movl    $555, 14(%rsp)
        movd    %xmm0, 10(%rsp)
        call    write
        addq    $40, %rsp
        ret
```

What I am looking for is a Rust solution to achieve the same thing. I don't mind necessarily if the Rust compiler can't currently produce code that is quite as efficient as above, but it is important that the above requirements are met: no heap allocation, no dynamic calculation of packet size or data offsets, no use of experimental/"unstable" language features.

I've been reading [the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) and trying to understand if and how I could do this in Rust, but so far I've gotten nowhere:

- Generic types don't seem to help, as they are more like "templates" in the original sense of the word than in the C++ sense. They also don't seem to allow parameterising by anything but types.
- Macros seem to be the metaprogramming tool of choice in Rust, but unless I'm not understanding correctly they operate on token streams and, unless there's a way I'm missing, they can't do the kind of thing that the `membuf` example does.

Essentially: I want a generic type, parameterised by buffer size, which can take a value and return a larger, fixed-size buffer, with the data appended at the end. But maybe that specification is too C++-centric and there's another tack that can be taken in Rust - I just need to figure out what it is!

Comment: You can use the [restruct](https://docs.rs/restruct_derive/0.1.0/restruct_derive/)-crate, which gives you compile-time/const packing and unpacking. As of now, it does require nightly, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slightly enlarging my comment with actual code: The [`restruct`](https://docs.rs/restruct_derive/0.1.0/restruct_derive/)-crate can do what you ask for; it does, however, require nightly as of now, as packing und unpacking are `const`-functions, which are not stable yet.

Given your example, after adding `restruct` and `restruct_derive` to the dependencies:

```
#![feature(const_int_conversion)]
#![feature(const_fn)]
#![feature(const_slice_len)]
#![feature(const_transmute)]


/// A packer/unpacker for two unsigned bytes, a group of eight unsigned bytes, a group of
/// four unsigned bytes and four padding bytes; all in little endian.
#[derive(restruct_derive::Struct)]
#[fmt="< 2B 8s 4s 4x"]
struct Foo;


fn main() {
    let data = (0xAA, 0xBB, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [4,3,2,1]);

    println!("The buffer has a size of {}", Foo::SIZE);

    let buf: [u8; Foo::SIZE] = Foo::pack(data);
    println!("Packed as {:?}", buf);

    let unpacked: <Foo as restruct::Struct>::Unpacked = Foo::unpack(buf);
    println!("Unpacked as {:?}", unpacked);
}
```

Comment: This is in fact decently close to what I was looking for, thanks. If it wasn't for requiring Nightly this would be just about perfect. It's interesting how large the implementation of the crate is compared to the C++ template, though!